# Access denied finding property "ro.serialno" on Android 11

Tags: java, android, module, android-permissions

i am having a problem with permissions on my Android 11. During the initialization of the React Native Module in , which I am implementing facing the following error

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.example.module">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />


<application
  tools:overrideLibrary="digital.paymentSystem.pay.sdk" 
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

What should i do to allow module finding the property of "ro.serialno"?

Thank you very much for your help.